# Renaming and/or copying domains in Amazon SimpleDB

Tags: dns, amazon-simpledb

My client decided to change the name of the project and requires that I change the domain names in our SimpleDB. I could not find any way, service, API call or tool to allow me to do that. I tried using the AWS tools for Eclipse as well as some other 3rd party tools.
At most, they allow you to delete a domain or export its contents to a data file. There's no import functionality.

My question/s:

1. Is there an easy way to rename a domain?
2. Failing that, is there an easy way to copy contents from one domain to another? If so, I'll just copy to the new one and delete the old one.
3. Failing 2, does someone have any ready-made code (preferably in PHP) to manually copy record-by-record from one domain to another?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to rename a domain, if the domain names MUST change, your only recourse is copying the data over manually; there is no automatic or API means to make the copy.

You may be able to use the online web services [SimpleBackr](http://simplebackr.com) or [BackupSDB](http://backupsdb.com) to backup the domains and restore to different domain names. I'm not positive that both services support restoring to different domain names, but I do know the people who run both sites and they are very helpful and responsive when it comes to supporting their services.

Whenever giving out your AWS secret key temporarily, even to trusted individuals, I always recommend that you generate a second key in the AWS Account website and give that out. When the temporary use is done, you can delete the second key, and the existing key used by your apps remains functional and secret.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't look like either of those services offer what I need, but thanks for the second key advice. Guess I'll have to write my own code to copy domain contents :(

Answer (score 4):

[SdbNavigator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sdbnavigator/ddhigekdfabonefhiildaiccafacphgg) lets you export and import data (in JSON format). You could export from domain A and import into domain B.

Comment: Brilliant answer! You're a lifesaver for making this known.